# page displaying media caption shortcodes

Tags: images, media, captions

I am developing my first wordpress theme. I encountered a problem in page section. I added a image in a page with add media button. When i viewed the page, it does display the image but also the caption part.

```
 [caption id="attachment_50" align="alignnone" width="300"] (actual image) [/caption]
```

I can't figure out why it's showing up. I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you outputting content via `the_content()`? That's the built in [Caption Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode).

Comment: Try switching to a default theme and see if the problem persists. If it does, try disabling plugins one by one and checking again. This is a popular technique for ruling out any troublemakers before we have to look further.

Comment: @Milo I am using `get_page_by_title()` function and assigning it to a variable. Then getting the content like  `$page = get_page_by_title('About'); $page->post_content`

Comment: @TheDearMedic It's working fine in default theme.

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405395/php-how-do-i-get-php-the-content-as-a-string-or-turn-it-into-a-strin). I used `apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content)` which stores it's html formatting.